# how to block loading an external script that forcibly shows ads on my website admin panel

Tags: javascript, php, html, loading, spam-prevention

Hi i'm a newbie and a while ago some probably malicious ad banner started showing only on my website's admin panel preventing me from the ability to scroll up and down, no where else on the website just there.
I inspected the code using chrome and started searching for clues of it everywhere in the website files but i couldn't seem to find it at all anywhere! I even replaced the files folder by folder with the original script files (non-installed) to see when the banner disappears but it didn't!
I would like to know if there is any method to block the urls and scripts responsible from the page?

This is a screenshot of the page:

[image: this is a screenshot of the page]

this is probably the code responsible for the banner and i noticed its under a second `<html>` and `<head>` tags

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <style type="text/css"><!--
    html, body, #partner, iframe {height:100%; width:100%; margin:0; padding:0; border:0; outline:0; font-size:100%; vertical-align:baseline; background:transparent;}body {overflow:hidden;}--></style>
    <meta name="expires" content="NOW"><meta name="GOOGLEBOT" content="index, follow, all"><meta name="robots" content="index, follow, all"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;"></head>
    <body><div id="partner"><style type="text/css">a.mp {float: left; margin: 3x 5px 1px 5px;padding: 4px; border-top: 1px solid #cec5a0; border-bottom: 2px solid #ea0; border-left: 1px solid #cec5a0; border-right: 2px solid #ea0; background: #f8f3d4; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; font: normal 14px Arial;  color: #04336d;} a.mp:hover { text-decoration: underline;}</style><div style="font-family: Arial; text-align:center"><table width="790" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" style="margin: 0 auto 0 auto; text-align:left;"><tr><td valign="middle">This domain is expired. If you're the owner, you can <a href="https://www.dynadot.com/community/help/question/renew-domain?drefid=121" rel="nofollow">renew</a> it. If you're not the owner, search for your next <a href="https://www.dynadot.com/domain/search.html?drefid=121" rel="nofollow">domain</a> and then <a href="https://www.dynadot.com/website-builder/?drefid=121" rel="nofollow">build your website</a> for free on <a href="https://www.dynadot.com/?drefid=121" rel="nofollow">Dynadot.com</a>!</td><td valign="middle"><a href="https://www.dynadot.com/market/auction/scriptolution.com?drefid=121" target="_blank" class="mp" rel="nofollow">Buy this domain</a></td><td align="right"><img src="http://parkcloud.dynadot.com/logo.gif" border="0" alt=""></td></tr></table></div></div><script type="e2d3d4d648ff87e4801c6399-text/javascript"><!--
     document.write(
             '<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript"'
                     + 'src="//sedoparking.com/frmpark/'
                     + window.location.host + '/'
                     + 'dynadotparking'
                     + '/park.js">'
             + '<\/script>'
     );
    --></script><script type="e2d3d4d648ff87e4801c6399-text/javascript" src="/hp_script.js"></script>
```